# Expand all groups by one click in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a simple question. How do we expand all groups by just one click? And also how do collapse all of them?

[image]

Comment: should be in the right click menu.

Comment: Also, are you familiar with the CTRL-M + CTRL-O, and CTRL-M + CTRL-P keyboard shortcuts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by Groups you mean Regions/Outlines, there a number of region controls in the Edit -> Outlining Menu (which also have handy hotkeys).

You may be interested in 'Toggle All Outlining' - Ctrl-M, Ctrl-L, or 'Collapse to Definitions' - Ctrl-M,Ctrl-O.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle All Outlining: Ctrl + M, L

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of a one-click method, but you can

- Stop Outlining *Ctrl-M, P*
- Toggle all Outlining *Ctrl-M, L*
- Toggle Outlining Expansion  *Ctrl-M, M*

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> - collapse/open the current parent region

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> - Collapse/Open all regions in document recursively (meaning you might get only one line in the document - one big namespace region which is collapsed or you'll see the entire page code uncollapsed

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> - Collapse all regions not recursively

Answer (score 1):

Cannot do this in 1 click. But mebbe 2.

Collapse to definitions: Hold your Ctrl key, hit M and then O.
Toggle All Outlining: Hold your Ctrl key, hit M and then L.

OR

Just go to the right-click menu in Outlining. You have all the options there.